# is there a way to relocate a linked collection that has its name changed?

Tags: linked-data, collections, outliner

I know there is a way to relocate a broken file in the outliner,
But is there a simple way to relocate a collection when it has its name changed ? (file is the same but the collection has a different name)

[image]

Thanks